# Picture not changing when program scrolled

Tags: java, eclipse, blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

Im working on a program, pretty simple. You simple enter a person's name into the field provided. click search and it searches a database and retrieves information. Including the picture. this works fine but i have one problem. If i do a search using peter and there are two 'peters' in the database. When i scroll. the picture does not change unless i click the picture field. I believe i posted the relavant code. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you

```
public class DriverSearchResultScreen extends MainScreen implements FieldChangeListener{
    LabelField header,title;

    LabelField lblLicenseNumber,lblFirstName,lblLastName,lblBirthDate,lblLicenseExpiry,lblLicenseType,lblLicenseStatus;

    ColoredMultiLineLabelField clblLicenseNumber,clblFirstName,clblLastName,clblBirthDate,clblLicenseExpiry,clblLicenseType,clblLicenseStatus;

    CustomButtonField btnSearch;

    CustomImageButton btnLeft,btnRight;

    CustomImageButton bmpfDriverPhoto;

    Vector licenseInfoData;

    int currentIndex = 0;

    public DriverSearchResultScreen(Vector licenseInfoData ) {

        this.licenseInfoData = licenseInfoData;
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        title = new LabelField("License",LabelField.USE_ALL_WIDTH);
        /*header.setBackground(bg);*/
        setTitle(title);

        bmpfDriverPhoto = new CustomImageButton(Bitmap.getBitmapResource("default-profile.png")){
            public boolean isFocusable() { return true; };
        };
        bmpfDriverPhoto.setChangeListener(this);
        add(bmpfDriverPhoto);

        header = new LabelField("",LabelField.FIELD_HCENTER|LabelField.USE_ALL_WIDTH){
                public void paint(Graphics g){
                    int col = g.getColor();
                    g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
                    super.paint(g);
                    g.setColor(col);
                }
                public int getPreferredWidth(){
                    return net.rim.device.api.system.Display.getWidth();
                }
            };
        this.getMainManager().setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createBitmapBackground(Bitmap.getBitmapResource("background.png")));
        header.setFont(Font.getDefault().derive(Font.SANS_SERIF_STYLE|Font.BOLD,25));

        add(header);
        add(new SeparatorField());

        Bitmap vfmBackground = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("rounded-border.png");
        VerticalFieldManager vfm = new VerticalFieldManager();
        vfm.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBitmapBorder(new XYEdges(12,12,12,12),vfmBackground));

        BHorizontalFieldManager hfm = new BHorizontalFieldManager();
        lblFirstName= new LabelField("First Name :");
        hfm.add(lblFirstName);
        clblFirstName = new ColoredMultiLineLabelField("Jhon",Color.GRAY);
        hfm.add(clblFirstName);
        vfm.add(hfm);
        vfm.add(new SeparatorField());

        BHorizontalFieldManager hfm1 = new BHorizontalFieldManager();

        lblLastName= new LabelField("Last Name :");
        hfm1.add(lblLastName);
        clblLastName = new ColoredMultiLineLabelField("Doe",Color.GRAY);
        hfm1.add(clblLastName);
        vfm.add(hfm1);
        vfm.add(new SeparatorField());

        BHorizontalFieldManager hfm2 = new BHorizontalFieldManager();

        lblBirthDate = new LabelField("Date Of Birth:");
        hfm2.add(lblBirthDate);
        clblBirthDate = new ColoredMultiLineLabelField("11-June-1982",Color.GRAY);
        hfm2.add(clblBirthDate);
        vfm.add(hfm2);
        vfm.add(new SeparatorField());

        BHorizontalFieldManager hfm3 = new BHorizontalFieldManager();

        lblLicenseNumber = new LabelField("License Number :");
        hfm3.add(lblLicenseNumber);
        clblLicenseNumber = new ColoredMultiLineLabelField("999999",Color.GRAY);
        hfm3.add(clblLicenseNumber);
        vfm.add(hfm3);
        vfm.add(new SeparatorField());


        BHorizontalFieldManager hfm4 = new BHorizontalFieldManager();

        lblLicenseType = new LabelField("License Type :");
        hfm4.add(lblLicenseType);
        clblLicenseType = new ColoredMultiLineLabelField("B",Color.GRAY);
        hfm4.add(clblLicenseType);
        vfm.add(hfm4);
        vfm.add(new SeparatorField());


        BHorizontalFieldManager hfm5 = new BHorizontalFieldManager();

        lblLicenseExpiry = new LabelField("Expiry Date:");
        hfm5.add(lblLicenseExpiry);
        clblLicenseExpiry = new ColoredMultiLineLabelField("25-Aug-2012",Color.GRAY);
        hfm5.add(clblLicenseExpiry);
        vfm.add(hfm5);
        vfm.add(new SeparatorField());


        BHorizontalFieldManager hfm6 = new BHorizontalFieldManager();

        lblLicenseStatus = new LabelField("Licenes Status:");
        hfm6.add(lblLicenseStatus);
        clblLicenseStatus = new ColoredMultiLineLabelField("Expired",Color.GRAY);
        hfm6.add(clblLicenseStatus);
        vfm.add(hfm6);
        vfm.add(new SeparatorField());

        add(vfm);

        btnLeft = new CustomImageButton(Bitmap.getBitmapResource("left-arrow-enable.png"),Bitmap.getBitmapResource("left-arrow-disable.png"));
        btnRight= new CustomImageButton(Bitmap.getBitmapResource("right-arrow-enable.png"),Bitmap.getBitmapResource("right-arrow-disable.png"));;

        HorizontalFieldManager arrowButtonHfm = new HorizontalFieldManager(){

            public int getPreferredHeight() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return btnLeft.getPreferredHeight()*2;
            }

            public int getPreferredWidth() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return Display.getWidth();
            }

            protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int count = getFieldCount();
                for(int i = 0 ; i < count ; i++ ){
                    Field f = getField(i);

                    if(f == btnLeft ){
                        setPositionChild(f, (getPreferredWidth() >> 1) - f.getPreferredWidth() - 30, getPreferredHeight()>>1);
                    }else if (f == btnRight ){
                        setPositionChild(f, (getPreferredWidth() >> 1) + 30, getPreferredHeight()>>1);
                    }
                    layoutChild(f, getPreferredWidth(), getPreferredHeight());
                }
                setExtent(getPreferredWidth(),getPreferredHeight());
            }

            public void subpaint(Graphics graphics){
                int count = getFieldCount();
                for(int i = 0 ; i < count ; i++ ){
                    net.rim.device.api.ui.Field f = getField(i);
                    paintChild(graphics,f);
                }
            }

        };

        /*add(new LabelField(){
            public int getPreferredHeight() {
                return 10;
            }
         });*/
        btnLeft.setChangeListener(this);
        btnRight.setChangeListener(this);
        btnLeft.setEnabled(false);
        arrowButtonHfm.add(btnLeft);
        arrowButtonHfm.add(btnRight);
        add(arrowButtonHfm);
        fillLicenseHolderInfoToField((LicenseObject)licenseInfoData.elementAt(currentIndex));
        setHeaderText();
        enableDisableButtons();
    }

    private void setHeaderText(){
        header.setText("Search Results. ( "+(currentIndex+1)+ " of "+ (licenseInfoData.size())+" )");
    }


     private void fillLicenseHolderInfoToField(LicenseObject licenseObject){
        bmpfDriverPhoto.setImage(licenseObject.getBmpImage());
        clblLicenseNumber.setText(licenseObject.getLicenseNum());
        clblFirstName.setText(licenseObject.getFirstName());
        clblLastName.setText(licenseObject.getLastName());
        clblBirthDate.setText(licenseObject.getDateOfBirth());
        clblLicenseExpiry.setText(licenseObject.getDateOfExpiry());
        clblLicenseType.setText(licenseObject.getLicenseType());
        clblLicenseStatus.setText(licenseObject.getLicenseStatus());
    }

    public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(field == btnRight){



            if( currentIndex < (licenseInfoData.size() - 1)){
                currentIndex++;
                fillLicenseHolderInfoToField((LicenseObject)licenseInfoData.elementAt(currentIndex));
            }
        }else if(field == btnLeft){
            if( currentIndex > 0 ){
                currentIndex--;
                fillLicenseHolderInfoToField((LicenseObject)licenseInfoData.elementAt(currentIndex));
            }
        }else if( field == bmpfDriverPhoto ){
            ImagePopDialog dialog = new ImagePopDialog("loader-image-box.png");
            Bitmap scaledBitmap = new Bitmap(300, 300);
            Bitmap btnBitmap    = bmpfDriverPhoto.getImage();
            btnBitmap.scaleInto(0, 0, btnBitmap.getWidth(), btnBitmap.getHeight(),
                        scaledBitmap, 0, 0, scaledBitmap.getWidth(), scaledBitmap.getHeight(), 1);
            dialog.add(scaledBitmap);
            UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(dialog);

        }

        enableDisableButtons();
        setHeaderText();
    }


    private void enableDisableButtons(){
        btnLeft.setEnabled((currentIndex > 0)?true:false);
        btnRight.setEnabled((currentIndex < (licenseInfoData.size() - 1))?true:false);
    }
    protected boolean onSavePrompt() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }
}
```

//Custom Image Button

```
package com.app.ui.component;

import net.rim.device.api.system.Bitmap;
import net.rim.device.api.system.Display;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Color;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Field;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Graphics;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.TouchEvent;

/**
 * * 
 * Class to Draw an Image Button
 */
public class CustomImageButton extends Field {

/** Bitmap for enabled image */
private Bitmap bmpEnabled;

/** Bitmap for disabled image */
private Bitmap bmpDisabled;

/** Label for Button*/
private String label;

private boolean mEnabled=true;

private int mCurrentTouchX = 0;

private int mCurrentTouchY = 0;

/**
 * Constructor with
 * @param image
 */
public CustomImageButton(Bitmap image) {
    super(Field.FOCUSABLE);
    this.bmpEnabled = image;
}

/**
 * Constructor with
 * @param enabled
 * @param disabled
 */
public CustomImageButton(Bitmap enabled,Bitmap disabled) {
    this(enabled);
    this.bmpDisabled = disabled;
}

public CustomImageButton(Bitmap enabled, Bitmap disabled, String label) {
    this(enabled);
    this.bmpDisabled = disabled;
    this.label = label;
}

protected void layout(int height, int width) {
    height = getPreferredHeight();
    width = getPreferredWidth();
    setExtent(width,height);

}

protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {
    if( isEnabled() ){
        if(isFocus()){
            int col = graphics.getColor();
            graphics.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            graphics.fillRect(0, 0, getPreferredHeight(), getPreferredHeight());
            graphics.setColor(col);
        }
        graphics.drawBitmap(5, 5, bmpEnabled.getWidth(), bmpEnabled.getHeight(), bmpEnabled,
            0, 0);          
        if(label != null && !label.equals("")) {
            graphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            graphics.drawText(label, bmpEnabled.getWidth()+5, (getPreferredHeight() - getFont().getHeight())/2);
        }
    }else{
        if( bmpDisabled != null )
            graphics.drawBitmap(5, 5, bmpDisabled.getWidth(), bmpDisabled.getHeight(), bmpDisabled,
                    0, 0);
        if(label != null && !label.equals("")) {
            graphics.setColor(Color.LIGHTGRAY);
            graphics.drawText(label, bmpEnabled.getWidth()+5, (getPreferredHeight() - getFont().getHeight())/2);
        }
    }
}

public int getPreferredWidth() {
    int prefwidth = 0;
    if(bmpEnabled != null) {    
        prefwidth =  bmpEnabled.getWidth(); 
    }   

    if(label != null && !label.equals("")) {    
        prefwidth = Display.getWidth()+10;
    }

    return (prefwidth+10);
}

public int getPreferredHeight() {
    if(bmpEnabled != null) {
        return bmpEnabled.getHeight()+10;
    }
    return 0;

}

/*protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {
    fieldChangeNotify(0);
    return true;
}*/

/**
 * To set the focused background color and invalidating the entire screen
 */
protected void onFocus(int direction) {
    invalidate();
}

/**
 * To set the unfocused background color and invalidating the entire screen
 */
protected void onUnfocus() {
    invalidate();
}

/**
 * Draws the focus indicator for this field. 
 * @param graphics
 * @param on
 */
protected void drawFocus(Graphics graphics, boolean on) {
    super.drawFocus(graphics, on);
}

protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time){
    if( mEnabled ){
        if (mCurrentTouchX >= 0 && mCurrentTouchX <= getPreferredWidth()
                && mCurrentTouchY >= 0
                && mCurrentTouchY <= getPreferredHeight())
            fieldChangeNotify(1);

        mCurrentTouchX = 0;
        mCurrentTouchY = 0;
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

protected boolean touchEvent(TouchEvent message) {
    if (mEnabled) {
        if (message.getEvent() == TouchEvent.CLICK) {
            mCurrentTouchX = message.getX(1);
            mCurrentTouchY = message.getY(1);
        }
    }
    return super.touchEvent(message);
}

public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.setEnabled(enabled);
    if(!enabled)
        this.focusRemove();
}

public void setImage(Bitmap image){
    this.bmpEnabled = image;
}

public Bitmap getImage(){
    return this.bmpEnabled;
}
```

}

Comment: I don't think this code does show anything that would cause a problem to **only** occur when you have two people with the same name.  However, from what you *do* show, the `ImapePopDialog` is only being shown when the user clicks on the `bmpfDriverPhoto` field, so that shouldn't be surprising.  Perhaps you need to show some more code?

Comment: ImagePopDialog causes the image to become larger when the picture is clicked. So that part is working as intended. 

However if the database has two people named Peter. the picture of the second peter only loads when the picture is clicked...Not when btnLeft or btnRight is clicked, while the other info such as birthdate changes

Comment: I java file in its entirety, thank u

Comment: the picture also refreshes and shows correctly if i scroll up a little

Comment: have you tried putting in a call to `bmpfDriverPhoto.invalidate()`, right after `bmpfDriverPhoto.setImage(licenseObject.getBmpImage());`?

Comment: no, havent...i will try that now

Comment: bmpfDriverPhoto.invalidate() gives the error. the method invalidate() from the type field is not visible. I also have no change in behavior

Comment: Ahhh.  I bet the problem is in your CustomImageButton class.  Can you post that code above?  By the way, naming your `bmpfDriverPhoto` variable that is probably not a good idea.  Especially since the original code you posted didn't have the type of that variable, the prefix `bmpf` leads a reader to believe that it is a BlackBerry `BitmapField`, which it's not.

Comment: i was wondering if there is like a refresh for the picture field that we can add to the Fieldchanged method

Comment: Like I said, you need to post the code that defines your `CustomImageButton` class.

Comment: Thank you for replying, Its the second potion of code. I linked it back up in my previous answer cause it was too long to post here. Again thanks for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `CustomImageButton` class you should change your setImage method:

```
public void setImage(Bitmap image){
    this.bmpEnabled = image;
}
```

by adding an invalidate to cause a redraw:

```
public void setImage(Bitmap image){
    this.bmpEnabled = image;
    invalidate();
}
```

The problem is that when your image is replaced, the change isn't seen on screen until the screen has been refreshed. `invalidate()` triggers a refresh of the screen(or layout), allowing any updates to be seen.

When you scroll or select the image, the `invalidate()` method is getting called so as the screen refreshes, which is why it isn't updating until then. A manual trigger of `invalidate()` solves this problem.

Make sure you are doing it on the Event Thread.